# Reloading UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When you call [table reloadData]; method does that simple recall the two methods used to originally build the table view:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
return tableLength;
 }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 return cell;
 }
```

Comment: Very short answer: yes, that is what should happen.

Comment: explain the problem in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. It also calls the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: NB: That is one of the methods listed in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is what happens. What else would you expect it to do?